# Boats passing through narrow tunnels

Tags: fluid-dynamics

When UK narrow boats pass through narrow tunnels the boats seem to stay centered in the tunnel. I assume that this is due to a "balancing effect" of water rapidly passing on either side?

Answer (score 0):

There will be some "self centering" cause by the Bernoulli effect, i.e. the same thing which explains why a table-tennis ball can be supported in a stable manner on a jet of air.

But since the relative velocities are low and the mass of a typical UK canal narrow boat is large (several tonnes - they have steel hulls, not fiberglass) I don't think this is the whole story.

From practical experience, steering a traditional boat is done using a rudder and standing at the stern of the boat, not in a wheelhouse nearer the bows as in most motor cruisers. Since any steering correction causes the stern to swing wide as you begin to turn, you are standing in the position which is most sensitive to observing the effect of deviating from a straight line.

You are also protected from one cause of narrow boat steering problems outside the tunnel, namely crosswinds, which have a significant effect on a boat with a maximum legal speed of 4 knots on the canals themselves (the legal speed may be higher on rivers).

Finally, canal boats were originally designed to carry up to 20 tons of cargo and be towed by horses, and bouncing off a stone or brick tunnel wall *gently* isn't a big deal - the boats were designed to be stopped by bumping into something, not by gunning an engine with a reversible propeller.

Most boats carry a few fenders permanently deployed on each side in any case, if only to avoid giving the owners of fiberglass boats a panic attack if they have to share a lock with several tons of steel plated hull :)